# Slow scrolling page on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, scroll

I would like to slow scrolling on my page on mobile.
The problem, if we have a long page, user can make a fast swipe and he can scroll very fast to get the end of the page. I would like to prevent this and if user do fast swipe, page scroll with max 200px to top or down (same for left and right).

have you any idea with jquery or js or css?

this example not working for me.

```
$("#bloc").on('touchend', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

cordially

Comment: i think  iscroll 5 plugin has the features you require  -- http://cubiq.org/iscroll-5

Comment: i tested it yesterday, but its not very fluid and especially when i am at the end of the page i can continue scrolling with a blank/white zone !!

Comment: im sure that can be fixed. do a demo here https://jsfiddle.net/ to check